# escape apostrophe in a regex string that starts and ends with apostrophe in dart

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to create a regular expression match for an email address and I intend to use it in a dart application.

I found the following regex for that:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

now i'm really new to dart but I understood that I can create regular expression strings with `r''` or `r""`.

now with dart I can escape characters with `\` so if I want to escape an apostrophe in a string that I started and ended with apostrophe I can just do this:

```
final String a = 'foo\'bar';
```

but with `final String a = r'foo\'bar'` I get an error. how can I properly escape that ?

thank you

Comment: You create a regular expression with `RegExp('...')` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html `r` is raw as mentioned below to tell if Dart should do string interpolation or not. https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `r''` does not mean "regular expression". [It means *"raw"*](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour), so backslash is interpreted as a literal backslash, and not as an escape character.

Not having to escape each backslash is useful for the kind of strings which often contain a lot of backslashes, such as regular expression patterns.

Regular expressions are created as instances of the [RegExp class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html).

You can concatenate raw strings that use different delimiters to create a single string for the whole pattern. In your case, this should work:

```
String pattern = r"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|" + r'"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])';
RegExp exp = new RegExp(pattern);
```

Comment: so I can just concat a raw string with a "'" with another raw string a solution right? is there a better approach ?

Comment: Yes, you can concat two or more raw string that use different delimiters.